# Pygame program quits after switching scenes (several while loops)

Tags: python, pygame

I am having an issue with my Pygame game. When navigating to the New Game screen, then going back and clicking the Options button, the game simple closes and doesn't give me an error or any indication of what is going wrong, but works if I click it without going to the New Game screen first.. Please tell me what I am missing.

Here's the code:

```
global new_game
global menu
global second_menu
global options_2
global galaxies

# start screen loop &variable
start_game = True
new_game = False
options_2 = False


def game_start():
    print ("hello")
    start_game = True
    options_2 = True
    while start_game:
        pygame.event.pump()
        screen.blit(background, background_rect)

        for option in menu:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    if (mouse_x >= corner1[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner1[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner1[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner1[1]+25):
                        print ("You clicked New Game")
                        start_game = False
                        options_2 = False
                        global new_game
                        new_game = True

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                start_game = False
                options_2 = False
                options = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    if (mouse_x >= corner3[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner3[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner3[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner3[1]+25):
                        print ("You clicked Load Game")
                        #start_game = False



            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    if (mouse_x >= corner5[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner5[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner5[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner5[1]+25):
                        global options_2
                        options_2 = True
                        start_game = False



game_start()                    



while options_2:
    screen.blit(background5, background4_rect)
    for option in second_menu:
        if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            option.hovered = True
        else:
            option.hovered = False
        option.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner1[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner1[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner1[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner1[1]+25):
                    current_volume = pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
                    new_volume = current_volume + 0.1
                    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(new_volume)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner3[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner3[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner3[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner3[1]+25):
                    current_volume1 = pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
                    new_volume1 = current_volume1 - 0.2
                    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(new_volume1)
                    #start_game = False
                    #running = True
                    #load_game = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner5[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner5[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner5[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner5[1]+25):
                    os.startfile('credits.txt','edit')

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner7[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner7[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner7[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner7[1]+25):
                    start_game = True
                    new_game = False
                    global options_2
                    options_2 = False
                    game_start()




        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                start_game = False
                options_2 = False
                options = False




# game loop
while new_game:

    # events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner2[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner2[0]+75) and (mouse_y >=corner2[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner2[1]+25):
                    start_game = True
                    new_game = False
                    options_2 = False
                    game_start()


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                if (mouse_x >= corner4[0]) and (mouse_x <= corner4[0]+150) and (mouse_y >=corner4[1]) and (mouse_y <= corner4[1]+25):
                    screen.blit(planet3, planet3_rect)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: could you produce a simpler (shorter) version of your code that shows the error?

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I've cut the code down somewhat, sorry to not know what I'm doing, I'm not too sure where the problem is in the remaining code. Thank you for the swift replies.

Comment: Are you just running the file and not through IDLE or another IDE? The reason I ask is because if it is the first, you will not be able to see any errors thrown. Running it in an IDLE will show you the error.

Comment: @SH7890 Yes I am running it through IDLE. I think it's just not reaching a loop and defaulting to quitting out of the program.

Comment: Your code is really convoluted. I recommend to learn more about [classes and object oriented programming](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=de&chapter=introduction_to_classes) in Python and pygame, and then implement a [finite state machine](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/) which serves as a scene manager. I can tell you what's going wrong in your program, but I think I'll better post that as an answer.

Comment: @skrx Ok, thank you very much for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's going on in your program:

1. The while loop in the `game_start` function is running. If you click on "New Game" or "Options", the while loop stops and the `game_start` function is left. Let's click "Options" first.
2. Now the program is running the `while options_2:` loop. If we click "Back", the `game_start` function is called within this while loop, so the `while start_game:` loop is running again and clicking on "Options" returns us to the `while options_2` loop correctly.
3. Let's click "New Game" in the start scene. Now the `while options_2:` loop is skipped and we're in the `while new_game:` loop. Clicking "Back" calls the `game_start` and runs its loop as usual, but what happens if we click "Options" now? We called `game_start()` from within the `while new_game` loop and we return to this position in the program when `game_start` is done. There's no way to jump back to the options loop above.
4. Since both `options_2` and `new_game` are `False` at this moment, the program leaves the last while loop and finishes.

---

What you could do is, wrap your `options_2` and `new_game` loops in functions as well. Then write a `main` (scene manager) function which switches between the three different scene functions. However, this can be done cleaner with a scene manager class like the [simple state machine here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look and fix my program when I get back from work and post the results.

Comment: Thank you it worked. The code is still far from completion but it's coming along.